# How are stdin and stdout connected on a ptty (like GNOME Terminal)

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

When writing simple c programs and executing them in the Terminal app, `printf` can affect `scanf`, like with whitespace characters, so it seems stdout and stdin are connected. How can this be?

Comment: Can you give an example what you're referring to?

Comment: Later when I'm not typing from a phone ;->

Answer (score 0):

If standard input and standard output are both connected to a terminal (the same terminal?), then the C library implementation usually arranges to flush standard output before starting an input operation on standard input.  It is a property of the C library, not of the pseudo-tty or `pty`.  The behaviour is not mandated by the [C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) or [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05), [AFAICT](https://www.acronymfinder.com/As-Far-As-I-Can-Tell-(AFAICT).html), but it is common behaviour on Unix-like systems, not least because it tends to make programs appear more responsive.

There's usually only one `t` in the abbreviation, mainly because the pseudo-terminal device names normally start `pty`.